# Why is it recommended to hide the bottom navigation bar after leaving the main fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have read a couple of times in tutorials that it is recommended not to show the bottom navigation bar after navigating deeper into each of the main fragments of each section.
So if you have 3 sections shown in the bottom nav bar, only the 3 landing fragments will show that bar, the rest of the fragments (as you navigate deeper) will hide it.

I know it has something to do with having a single backstack, but I don't really know the real explanation or what would be the problem of not hiding it.

Could someone explain please?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can attributed to the Master-details UI pattern.
[Master-detail wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface.)

[Android tutorial - Master-Detail views with Navigation Components](https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974)

You have main screen which is an activity that acts as you application single entry point, the bottom navigation bar holds the main points of interest you want your user to interact with or engage, with say [Feed, Messages, Profile], each one of those is a master view that has a set of child view linked to it, for example feeds to have your feeds for categories like [Music, Technology, ..].

From a UX point of view hiding the bottom nav-bar when navigating the children of a main/master view and have back button or home button that returns you to main screen that way your user understands the flow of your application and has easier time navigating it, and may not accidental click the [profile] button while scrolling down the feeds list.

Comment: That makes total sense from an UX/Design perspective, however i thought there would be a technical reason for recommending it. Kind of... since there is a single backstack, if the user navigates to another section and presses back, it will be taken again to the previous section (so, the backstack is unique and lineal).
If it's just a UX recommendation then it's easy to understand.

Comment: If you are using the Navigation components (check the link in my answer) you don't have to worry about back button navigation handling and the back-stack since the nav. component takes care of that for you, that's one the main reasons this Jetpack component was introduced, to resolve the problems developers had with back-stacking of fragments and fragment transition. try the Navigation component code lab and you'll see how it makes for better fragment navigation setup.